# Why doesn't rTorrent support all types of torrent file?

Tags: torrent-client, rtorrent

When I tried to download a torrent file using rtorrent it showed:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

It happens only for some files, not for all. Why does it happen for some torrent files?

Answer (score 0):

the torrent has most likely a `(` in the title that you need to escape.

Eg:

Wrong:

```
'Torrent File Name (2009)'
```

Correct:

```
'Torrent File Name \(2009\)'
```

Comment: thats okay, but how to do that when you pass the torrentname to a script when a torrent finishes downloading?